# Identifying regression with ARIMA errors

Tags: time-series

I have read form several sources that in order to identify the best **ARIMA** process for regression model with *ARIMA errors*, one should start by estimation of the proxy `ARIMA(2,0,0)(1,0,0)` model and then read form *ACF* and *PACF* plots to develop the best model (see https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1).

But isn't the better way just to start with simple *OLS* regression and its residuals and not residuals from proxy model that already include *ARIMA* components?

Can anybody tell is there any specific advantages for one approach over the other?